# Objective-C class type error

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have a view created like the following:

```
Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(className);

UIView *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

The above works, but I was hoping to know if it is possible to replace `UIView` and create the instance like this:

```
MyClass *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

? It gives an error:

> use of undeclared identifier myView

Why can I use it like this? And how can I use it this way?

So I then tried:

```
const char *class = [MyClass UTF8String];
Class MyClass = objc_allocateClassPair([UIView class], class, 0);
MyClass *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

But this also doesn't work. It doesn't give the above warning but would when I subsequently do:

```
myView.backgroundColor = ....;
```

> use of undeclared identifier myView

How can I be able to use the class type dynamically? And what is the difference between:

```
NSClassFromString(className);
```

and:

```
objc_allocateClassPair
```

?

Comment: Is MyClass actually a subclass of UIView?

Comment: @Tander No, at the point it is just `Class`; so I then tried using `objc_allocateClassPair`. But neither is working.

Comment: What is NSClassFromString(className) ?

Comment: @Tander `className` is the name of a class, which is a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: MyClass is effectively a variable. You can't use it as a type name any more than you could say `float aFloat = 1.0; aFloat anotherFloat = 2.0`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay - so it seems when you do this:

```
Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(className);
```

You're setting `MyClass` up as a `UIView` since `className` is a subclass of `UIView`

Which is why when you do this:

```
UIView *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

It works. You're allocating and initialising `myView` as a `UIView` object. No problems here.

When you do this:

```
MyClass *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

You get a crash.

Reason:

Here you're allocating and initialising `myView` as a `MYClass` object. Which is not a `UIView` since `MyClass` has no idea what `initWithFrame` means and thus, doesn't respond to it - crash. In fact - that code shouldn't even compile.

You're going about this in an ass about face kinda way. You're trying to convert a class that is not a subclass of UIView into a class that knows what UIView is and is able to respond to its messages.

AlieN's answer would solve the compiler error - since `id` is "Any type of class" and with introspection it would work. However, I don't like this method of solving your issue - its a hack.

Why not make `MyClass` a subclass of UIView and allow it to receive messages. Because, that's how you're trying to use it... as a `UIView` object.

As I am not sure what `MyClass`'s actual job is, its difficult to solve the issue another way, without the need to subclass.

Can you elaborate on what MyClass's job is? (It seems like you're trying to give it more than one job here)

**Edit**

From your comments below - you're doing this:

```
Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(className);
MyClass *myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
```

If so the crash is simple to explain:

Its crashing because the second line of the above code creates a *new* instance of `MyClass` which is just a standard Class (Not a subclass of UIView) your first line become redundant.

Comment: Right, it doesn't compile. But `MyClass` is a subclass of `UIView`. `UIView *myView.... init...];` works, but if I wanted to send a message to this object define in `MyClass`, it wouldn't respond to it. That's why I really wanted to know if we could do `MyClass *myView = ....` All in all, I would like to do this as dynamically as possible.

Comment: Since you said MyClass is not a SubClass of UIView it won't respond to those messages. If it were, initWithFrame would work in your second line of code in your question. You cannot dynamically change its type in the way you're trying to do. In your working code - you're setting MyClass up as a UIView class. Without doing that - nothing else (besides making MyClass a subclass of UiView) will work properly.

Comment: I thought that this line: `Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(className);` would just return an "opaque" class type, even `className` is a string of a class that is a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: Okay, wait - you're including that line all the time? If so the reason you're getting a crash is the second line recreates MyClass and sets it back to just a Class and not a UIView Class.

Comment: Edited my answer - is this what you're doing?

Comment: Yes, thanks for edit. But the thing is, with `className` I could just use a string to create a class. And imagine if I changed the name of this string in the future that represents another class which would still be subclass of `UIView`, that's why I do it this way. +1.

Comment: Yup and that works fine. To answer your original question: nope - you have to do it the way you originally did it for simplicity. Introducing id and introspection will make it more complex than it needs to be. Feel free to accept the answer if its helped.

Comment: I would, but at the moment it doesn't seem to solve it. To reiterate the scenario: I set up a string, create a class from it, then create object with it, then with this object - send a message to it that is already defined in this class, add `gestureRecognizer` to it etc etc, thing one would do with a view. For simplicity, let say I had a method in MyClass named "touched", I cannot add a gesture to it (target/action) because the compiler complains that it doesn't see the method "touched". From my understanding, it resolves it to `UIView` and not `MyClass`.

Comment: I'm sure you could make this whole thing much simpler. It sounds like you're reusing MyClass for different things. If you like - I'd be happy to chat about this over an IM of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(className);
id myView = [[MyClass alloc] initWithFrame:..];
[myView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

---

But it will compile even if you will try to

```
[myView addObject:...];
```

And will crash.

Comment: This is fine - but it will crash if its set the incorrect message. You should edit the answer to include introspection to be a little safer, when using id.

Comment: In addition, if later on I would like to send a message specific to this object, it would not respond.

Comment: @Unheilig - Why would it not respond? Method resolution is a pure run-time thing in Objective-C. You can invoke any method on any object, even if all you have is an `id` (instead of the proper type). Whether the compiler gets the argument values/return value right in such a scenario is a related but different matter.

Comment: @Dirk I just tried your suggestion by trying to add a `gestureRecognizer` to `myView` and set the target to it and selector defined in `MyClass`, but I think the compile sees only `UIView` not `MyClass`.

Comment: @Dirk And by the way, why wouldn't the compiler get the argument values/return values right in such a scenario? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig - If you have only an `id`-typed reference, the compiler knows nothing about the referent except that it is some instance of some class. How should it know about the methods supported by that instance, let alone the return value and parameter types? I think, that this is one of the reasons, why Objective-C methods have names like `stringByAppendingString:` (etc.) instead of just `append:`. This scheme encodes the name of the result value type as well as the argument types in the method name.